# Fitting a label spanning the leftover space in a grid

Tags: output-formatting, grid-layouts

I would like to fit a label for a grid of images in the remainder of the columns on the last row. A minimal example and an attempt follows where the letters represent images.

```
Style[#, 44] & /@ CharacterRange["A", "Z"] // 
   Partition[#, UpTo[4]] & // Grid // Framed

Style[#, 44] & /@ 
    CharacterRange["A", "Z"]~
     Join~{Style[#, 8] &@"Letters in the English Alphabet"} // 
   Partition[#, UpTo[4]] & // Grid // Framed
```

[image]

How can this be accomplished? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe modify your grid along these lines:

```
(Style[#, 44] & /@ CharacterRange["A", "Z"])~Join~
{Pane[Style[#, 8] &@"Letters in the English Alphabet", 50], SpanFromLeft} //  
Partition[#, UpTo[4]] & // Grid // Framed
```

Specifically, use a `Pane` to easily wrap the text and use `SpanFromLeft` so that the label text flows across all remaining columns. I chose a width of 50 for `Pane`, but maybe you can derive that automatically. Or maybe `Pane` won't work, in which case we'd need more info.

Oh, also note that I added parentheses, `(Style[#, 44] & /@ CharacterRange["A", "Z"])`, to force the desired precedence.

Comment: There is a hard return in front of `// Partition...`